# How to adjust function without specifying dataset

Tags: r

I have a function that basically filters an `SPV` row, as you can see below. Note that I do `return_coef <- function(df1, idd,dmda, CategoryChosse) {` However, I would not like `df1` as an argument of the function, but rather the attributes of the `df1` dataset, which in this case is  `Id`, `date1`, `Week`, `Category`, `DR1` and `DRM`. How can I adjust this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)


df1 <- structure(
  list(
    Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
    date1 = c("2022-01-06","2022-01-06","2022-01-06","2022-01-06"),
    date2 = c("2022-01-02","2022-01-03","2022-01-09","2022-01-10"),
    Week = c("Sunday","Monday","Sunday","Monday"),
    Category = c("EFG", "ABC","EFG","ABC"),
    DR1 = c(200, 300, 200, 200),
    DRM0 = c(300, 300, 300, 300),
    DRM01 = c(300, 300, 300, 300),
    DRM02 = c(300,300,300,300),
    DRM03 = c(300,300,300,300),
    DRM04 = c(300,250,350,350)),row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

return_coef <- function(df1, idd,dmda, CategoryChosse) {
  
x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DRM0"))

x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
PV<-select(x,Id, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))

med<-PV %>%
  group_by(Id,Category,Week) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(ends_with("PV"), median))

SPV<-df1%>%
  inner_join(med, by = c('Id','Category', 'Week')) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^DRM0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                  get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
  select(Id:Category, DRM01_DRM01_PV:last_col())

SPV <- SPV %>%
  filter(Id==idd,date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) 

return(SPV)

}

return_coef(df1, "1", "2022-01-10", "ABC")

`summarise()` has grouped output by 'Id', 'Category'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
  Id      date1      date2   Week Category DRM01_DRM01_PV DRM02_DRM02_PV DRM03_DRM03_PV DRM04_DRM04_PV
1  1 2022-01-06 2022-01-10 Monday      ABC            250            250            250            300
```

Comment: A combination of `!!`, `{{`, `...`, `substitute` and `deparse` is probably what you are after, however, I'm not clear on what you mean by *and so on*. As an aside, I suggest chopping the function into smaller functions, this may make this question a lot easier to solve.

Comment: @DonaldSeinen, I adjusted the function and question, please can you look?

Comment: This question is a bit unclear to me. Do you want to call your function with the columns in `df1` as arguments? Do you then want to call the function once per row, or for all the rows combined?

Comment: Exactly! I intend to use the dataset columns instead of using `df1` as a function argument. Regarding your second question, I don't quite understand.

Comment: Do you want `DRM0` to be included in the output and treated the same as `DRM01` - `DRM04`? In your function, it's captured by `starts_with("DRM0")`, but not by `matches("^DRM0\\d+$")` or `DRM01_DRM01_PV:last_col()`, so doesn't affect the output in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* what you want is to be able to specify arbitrary columns from a dataframe to be used as `Id`, `date1`, `Week`, etc inside `return_coef()`, rather than having to use a dataframe that already has those specific column names. If so, you can use the tidyeval embracing operator, `{{`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

return_coef <- function(.data, 
                        Id,
                        date1,
                        date2,
                        Week,
                        Category,
                        DR1,
                        DRM_vars, 
                        idd, 
                        dmda, 
                        CategoryChosse) {
  .data %>% 
    group_by({{ Id }}, {{ Category }}, {{ Week }}) %>%
    mutate(across({{ DRM_vars }}, ~ median({{ DR1 }} - .x) + .x)) %>% 
    select(
      {{ Id }}, {{ date1 }}, {{ date2 }}, {{ Week }}, {{ Category }}, 
      {{ DRM_vars}}
    ) %>% 
    rename_with(~ str_glue("{.x}_{.x}_PV"), {{ DRM_vars }}) %>% 
    filter(
      {{ Id }} == idd, 
      {{ date2 }} == dmda, 
      {{ Category }} == CategoryChosse
    ) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
}

# test w dataframe with different var names
df2 <- rename_with(df1, ~ paste0(.x, ".2"))

df2 %>% 
  return_coef(
    Id = Id.2, date1 = date1.2, date2 = date2.2, Week = Week.2, 
    Category = Category.2, DR1 = DR1.2, DRM_vars = DRM01.2:DRM04.2, 
    idd = "1", dmda = "2022-01-10", CategoryChosse = "ABC"
  )
```

Output:

```r
Id.2    date1.2    date2.2 Week.2 Category.2 DRM01.2_DRM01.2_PV  DRM02.2_DRM02.2_PV DRM03.2_DRM03.2_PV DRM04.2_DRM04.2_PV
   1 2022-01-06 2022-01-10 Monday        ABC                250                 250                250                300
```

**A few notes:**

1. You can pass any valid <[`tidy-select`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html)> expression, capturing any number of columns, to the `DRM_vars` argument.
2. I was able to simplify your function a bit while still reproducing your example output. Be sure to test with your actual data and let me know if it doesn't work as intended.
3. Your question stated, "I would not like `df1` as an argument of the function," which puzzled me. I think I've captured what you actually want, even though this function does still take a dataframe as an argument. If you truly don't want to include a dataframe in the function call, you *could* specify a dataframe in the body of the function as illustrated below, but I'm not sure why you'd want to do this. If there's something I'm missing, please let me know in a comment.

Modification with no passed dataframe:

```
return_coef2 <- function(Id,
                        date1,
                        date2,
                        Week,
                        Category,
                        DR1,
                        DRM_vars, 
                        idd, 
                        dmda, 
                        CategoryChosse) {
  df1 %>% 
    group_by({{ Id }}, {{ Category }}, {{ Week }}) %>%
    # rest of function identical to above
    # ...
}

return_coef2(
  Id, date1, date2, Week, Category, DR1, DRM_vars = DRM01:DRM04, idd = "1", 
  dmda = "2022-01-10", CategoryChosse = "ABC"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modified as less as possible your code and came up with this solution:

```
#First, create a second dataframe to test (as zephryl did):
df2 <- rename_with(df1, ~ paste0(.x, ".2"))

#Defining default variables

default_vars <- names(df1)

#Create a list of datasets

df_list<- list(df1,df2)
```

Create loop to run the code on each dataset from the list, without using them as arguments (or the list object as well).

```
#return_coef function:

return_coef <- function(vars,idd,dmda, CategoryChosse) {
  
  for (i in 1:length(df_list)){
    
    df1<-df_list[[i]]
    colnames(df1)<-vars
    
    x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DRM0"))
    
    x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
    
    PV<-select(x,Id, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
    
    med<-PV %>%
      group_by(Id,Category,Week) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(ends_with("PV"), median))
    
    SPV<-df1%>%
      inner_join(med, by = c('Id','Category', 'Week')) %>%
      mutate(across(matches("^DRM0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                      get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                    .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
      select(Id:Category, DRM01_DRM01_PV:last_col())
             SPV <- SPV %>%
               filter(Id==idd,date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse)
             print(SPV)
             }

}
```

Then run:

```
return_coef(default_vars,"1", "2022-01-10", "ABC")
```

Two assumptions I made:

1. The names of df1 are the default variables for the remaining potential datasets;
2. The variables are in the same order.